# Host key verification failed Xcode with Mavericks Server

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, git-submodules, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to get a CI setup going and have got Mavericks server downloaded and linked with Xcode all on one machine.

Here's the set up:

1. Two git repos, hosted on OS X  server, named `CI` and `CISubmodule`.
2. `CISubmodule` added as a submodule to `CI`

Every time I add bot I get a `Host key verification failed` error on integration. It's clear from the logs that the server is unable to clone `CISubmodule` due to an authentication error (I've tried SSH, HTTP, HTTPS) but I don't know why it's failing authentication.

I've set up the server so that logged in users can read and write.

I've tried everything [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625530/could-not-create-directory-var-teamsserver).

I'm guessing it's because the server is running as `teamsserver` and the repo is probably under my username, but I can't figure out how to give it permission to clone. Could it be that the SSH key requires a password? If so, how do I set it up so that it doesn't need a password any more?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case and I am not sure what happend exactly, I think the reason was I had more remote repository accesses and ssh keys pointing git-server side pointing to the same repository.

Deleting the remote repository accesses and cleaning up authorized_keys file helped.

I can confirm the CI server works with submodules, but make sure the .gitmodules file and xccheckout file point to the same repos

Comment: Both the .gitmodules file and xccheckout are pointing to the same repo. Could you elaborate on the deleting of remote repository accesses? Both the repos have one local and one remote, which points to the hosting location on the server (e.g. http://<comp>.local/git/CISub.git.)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use passphrase-LESS keys for os x server to properly connect to 3rd party hosted git repos. it cannot connect with there is a passphrase needed.

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

it worked for us

Answer (score 0):

One thing that helped me was to change my submodule URLs to use HTTPS instead of SSH.

When doing this, make sure that Xcode is actually using the new URLs. Even though I made the changes and pushed them, Xcode was caching the SSH URLs and using them. Remove all your SSH URLS from your server, then also remove them from your client under `Preferences->Accounts`. Then restart the server and restart Xcode, confirming that the new HTTPS URLs are being used when you create your bot.